# TreeView - Set default select item and highlight (blue) this item

Tags: c, winapi, treeview

When I create a TreeView Control, insert several items, then I use TVM_SELECTITEM to select an default item. But this item is not highlighted by blue color. Later, if I use mouse or keyboard to select an item, it will be highlighted.

So how to make the default item being highlighted?

This is the function and parameters I used:

```
SendMessage(hTreeView, TVM_SELECTITEM, TVGN_CARET, (LPARAM)hItem);
```

---

I just found I just need to set focus on TreeView control and it works.

But how do I have a gray highlight on the item even when TreeView lose the focus, when users select some options, like the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you figured out the answer to your original question, I'll answer your second:

> I just found I just need to set focus on TreeView control and it
>   works.
>
> But how do I have a gray highlight on the item even when TreeView lose
>   the focus, when users select some options, like the following picture:

Give your TreeView control the `TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` window style. (Incidentally, the screenshot you show uses a ListView control, not a TreeView control.  ListView controls have an equivalent `LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS` style.)